# Grails: How to put javascript/ajax in taglib?

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, taglib

How to put javascript code in grails taglib?
example I have grails taglib :

```
def ajaxSelect = { attrs ->
        out << """
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
                ....
        });
        });         
        </script>
        """
```

I get the following error :

> either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value
>   expression "${5}"

What i miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, escape it:) Add a `\` before every `$` in your multiline string.